# Building shared library with ffmpeg results in relocation error

Tags: ffmpeg

I need to create a custom shared library that internally uses ffmpeg functions. The idea is to create one fat shared library, say, myffmpeg.so.

I first build ffmpeg code (3.3.1 as of this post). During configuration, I specify `-fPIC` via `--extra-cflags` and `--extra-cxxflags.` I also specify `-enable-pic` during the configuration. After running configure and make,  various archive files such as `libswscale.a, libavformat.a,` etc. are successfully created.

Next, I try to build my shared library:

```
gcc -fPIC -Ixxx  mywrapper.cpp 
gcc -shared -o myffmpeg.so mywrapper.o -Lxxx -lswscale -lavformat...
```

However, this results in an error:

```
Relocation R_X86_64_PC32 against symbol ff_M24A can not be
used when making a shared object;
```

Looks like I am missing some compiler/linker setting. Can someone please point me in the right direction? Regards.

Answer (score 3):

Here is how I solved the problem. You need to add "-Wl,-Bsymbolic" to ldflags during configuration. Also, when you create the shared library, you need to pass the same parameter to the linker. Regards.

Comment: This took me way too long to find. It makes absolutely no sense to me why, even building FFmpeg with -fPIC, these errors were still cropping up, telling me to rebuild with -fPIC! But if you need to bundle FFmpeg in a single shared library, this answer seemed to work for me. You should accept it. Also, worth clarifying that this flag is added to the link step of the shared library, not as additional flags when building FFmpeg.

Comment: I encountered the same problem when linking an indirect dependence of my project. That dependence was already built with `-fPIC`. `-Bsymbolic` also fixed for me but I've the feeling here it's just the linker that is confused for no reason and it could be bugged (I'm using `ld` from Android NDK which uses old gcc version). IMO, reworking link ordering could also fix, or use an alternative linker like `ldd`, when avaiable.

Answer (score 0):

If you need shared libraries, build ffmpeg with `--enable-shared`, which will generate shared objects `libswscale.so`, `libavformat.so`, etc. The `.a` files are static libraries built by default configuration.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I do want static libraries so that I can create one fat .so file instead of several .so files.